# How cpu allocated to a process?

Tags: tomcat, cpu, monitoring, performance-testing, cpu-architecture

In my environment we having issue with high cpu utilization processes with more than 200% but we using 14cpus server. Mostly in the case of Tomcat process . Can you please explain how cpu allocated to a process ?

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen >100% on Windows, so I am going to assume that you are running on some Unix / Linux distro.

On a 14 core machine, you may see CPU climb as high as 1400% - as each of your 14 cores has it own 0 -> 100% capacity.

Using `top`, and then pressing the number `1`, will show the usage of each individual core.

```
top - 02:10:29 up 124 days,  4:52,  1 user,  load average: 0.25, 0.29, 0.28
Tasks: 153 total,   1 running, 152 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  1.2 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  1.2 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :  1.2 us,  1.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16431812 total,   716508 free,  5590424 used, 10124880 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8265724 total,  7145596 free,  1120128 used. 10221956 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
25836 mclark    20   0  146100   2028   1412 R   1.2  0.0   0:00.02 top
32532 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1.2  0.0   0:02.18 kworker/2:0
    1 root      20   0  310388 123720   2764 S   0.0  0.8  50:34.97 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:05.13 kthreadd
```

Obviously, if your process is using >100%, it is `multithreading`, if a process were to only use a single thread, it would only be run on a single core.